# Не нажимается кнопка на сайте selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jframe

пытаюсь заставить программу войти на сайт. Для этого надо для начала перейти на страницу, где просят пароль (если пытаюсь задать ссылку `https://edostavka.by/login?screen=withPassword` - программа все равно открывает `https://edostavka.by/login?screen=phone`)
И при этом неважно какую ссылку я ставлю, `selenium` все равно не видит кнопку, как бы я её не искал(через `XPATH`, `LINK_TEXT`, `CLASS_NAME`) и выдает ошибку:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Войти с паролем"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x00FEF243]
    (No symbol) [0x00F77FD1]
    (No symbol) [0x00E6D04D]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9C0B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9C22B]
    (No symbol) [0x00ECE612]
    (No symbol) [0x00EB85D4]
    (No symbol) [0x00ECC9EB]
    (No symbol) [0x00EB8386]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9163C]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9269D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01289A22+2655074]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0127CA24+2601828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01098C0A+619850]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01097830+614768]
    (No symbol) [0x00F805FC]
    (No symbol) [0x00F85968]
    (No symbol) [0x00F85A55]
    (No symbol) [0x00F9051B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x771800F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779C7BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779C7B8E+238]
```

Вместо `sleep` использовал `WebDriverWait` и `ExpectedConditions`, но разницы не было. Из того, что вычитал - возможно как-то на это влияют `iframe` или `scripts` на странице. Но `iframe` 4 штуки и все вроде бы пустые, а что со `scripts` делать и нужно ли так и не понял.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from fake_useragent import UserAgent as ua
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ua = ua(browsers='chrome')

driver_service = Service(executable_path=r'C:\Users\37533\Desktop\dostavka\dostavka\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={ua}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.maximize_window()

#url = 'https://edostavka.by/login?screen=withPassword'
url = 'https://edostavka.by/login?screen=phone'
try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'phone').send_keys('132456789')
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Войти с паролем').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать поиск по xpath следующим образом:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Войти с паролем']")
```

С помощью `LINK_TEXT` и `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT` я так же не смог найти элемент, но подобным образом элемент был найден:

```
url = 'https://edostavka.by/login?screen=phone'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Войти с паролем']")
print('element found')
```

вывод:

```
element found
```

---

`<iframe>` может повлиять на поиск, если элемент находится внутри этого тэга, но в данном случае это не так.

С тэгами `<script>` вам наверняка вообще не нужно ничего делать при процессе парсинга или автоматизации через selenium

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но это не помогло. 
В моем случае мне  помогло другое решение - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74829983/20795958]

Comment: @Pr1m3raaa этот код не должен логиниться на сайт, он просто находит элемент. Если элемент был бы не найден, то возникла бы ошибка. Так как в вашем коде отрабатывает строчка: `driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'phone').send_keys('132456789')` , но не отрабатывает следующая, значит вы можете найти элемент вне div'a с "принятием cookies", поэтому совсем необязательно их принимать. А если вы пытались нажать на найденный `<span>` или отправить туда номер, то нужно было найти родительский `<button>` и кликать уже на него. Другими словами, в этом ответе не полноценный код для аутентификации на сайте

Comment: Я имею в виду, что через `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Войти с паролем']")` питон по прежнему не находил кнопку и выдавал ошибку. А через `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button button_size_large button_type_subtle phone_button__2Z9fs phone_button__padding__e0VFd']")` нашло

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
driver.get('https://edostavka.by/login?screen=phone')

# Нажимаем на принять cookies если всплывает окно
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]').click()
# time.sleep(3)

# Или закрываем окно
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(3)

# Нажимаем на Войти с паролем
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
```